# Elasticsearch document_missing_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm seeing `document_missing_exception` when upsert data to Elasticsearch (ES version 7.4).
Per the exception name it seems due to the requested document does not exist in Elasticsearch. While the upsert script succeeds with retry.

Is that true `document_missing_exception` is only due to the requested document does not exist in Elasticsearch?
Any information regarding document_missing_exception are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct, that `document_missing_exception` is only due ti requested document doesn't exist in ES,  you can easily look at ES source code to find that and see, that only place where its called is from `UpdateRequest` and [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/update/UpdateRequest.java#L697) method comment explains it much better:

**From the ES code**

```
  /**
     * Sets the index request to be used if the document does not exists. Otherwise, a
     * {@link org.elasticsearch.index.engine.DocumentMissingException} is thrown.
     */
    public UpdateRequest upsert(IndexRequest upsertRequest) {
        this.upsertRequest = upsertRequest;
        return this;
    }
```